# Two Ubuntu software applications

Tags: 20.04, software-center

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion dv6, dual boot with Windows 7. It had been working fine till today morning when the Ubuntu software wouldn't open and I looked online for solutions. I tried reinstalling the gnome-software/snap-software application and now I have Ubuntu Software and Software application. Out of the two only the Software one opens and I can navigate to find the various applications. As for the second one, the issue is still not resolved. I open it and the activities show Ubuntu Software with a loading sign but then it goes away and app isn't opened. How can I remove Ubuntu Software application or merge them into one of possible??

Comment: @vanadium ever since I've run the first command in the thread you mentioned, the internet has crashed. Download speed in terminal drops from 300kbps to 0 at a regular interval. I'm now looking at those and will come back if it fixes. If not I'll reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @vanadium thank you. The issue is resolved though now the wifi issue seems to be more persistent. Thanks again.